# What is the intuitive idea behind this claim on the divisor function?

Tags: number-theory, divisor-counting-function

I want to understand the claim
$$
\lim_{X \to \infty} \frac{\#\{n \le X : d(n) \equiv 0 \mod m \}}{X} = 1,
$$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is fixed and $d(n)$ is the divisor function. I think that it means if we pick a positive integer $n$ at random, then $d(n) \equiv 0 \mod m$ with probability $1$, but I want to understand why this is true from a intuitive perspective. Also a reference for a proof would be great.

Comment: Interesting.  I suppose the point is that $d(n)=\prod (a_i+1)$ where the $a_i$ are the exponents in the prime factorization for $n$.  Assuming that most numbers have "many" prime factors and that the $a_i$ are scattered amongst the congruence classes for $m$, then sure...it seems likely that one factor in the product would be divisible by $m$.   Making this rigorous sounds thorny though...

Comment: what is a reference for the claim?

Comment: It was posed by my professor in a class, I'm not sure where else one can find it. I am 99% sure I have not made any transcription errors.

Comment: For a simpler example, could it be proved that $$ \lim_{X \to \infty} \frac{\# \{n \le x : d(n) \equiv 2 \mod 4\}}{X} = 0? $$ I have a very poor feel for these types of problems. I believe this is equivalent to asking for the proportion of $n \le x$ having exactly 1 odd power in its prime factorization.